# Align checkbox right most side in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to allign the checkboxes in a list view to right most part of the screen.

my Layout is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="right|center" />
```

But When i run this i get the output as checkboxes right next to the textview

[image: Output of code]

Found mistake.. its in mainactivity.. i have put the the width of listview as wrap content instead of fill parent

Comment: put layout weight 1 to your linear layout above checkbox and remove weight from checkbox give it fixed width

Comment: @Pavan its not working.. the whole textviews become shaded and i cant even see the checkbox

Comment: have you added the fixed width to checkbox check my updated answer you can modify according your requirement

Answer (score 2):

Use `RelativeLayout` for ChechBox Section and Add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` .Try this way ,Let me inform .

Okay,You can set 2 Textview and ChechBox on same row using layout weight (Linear Layout). And set gravity,layout gravity right for ChechBox.

Comment: Putting checkbox inside a relative layout makes the whole thing not working.

Comment: Found the mistake. I have put the listviews width as wrap content instead of fill parent in mainactivity.. Anyway thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Number"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Number"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
       android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="right|center" />
    </LinearLayout>
```